# How to delete DB data by given ID using SQL query in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have written the following controller code for select query :

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/listuserpermissions/{systemId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public List<AlicePermissions> userPermissionsforRole(@PathVariable("systemId") int systemId) {

    List<Object[]> rows = userPermissionService.roleuserPermissionforRole(systemId);

    List<AlicePermissions> alicePermissions = new ArrayList<AlicePermissions>();
    for (Object[] object : rows) {
        AlicePermissions alicePermissions2 = new AlicePermissions();
        alicePermissions2.setPermId((Integer) object[0]);
        alicePermissions2.setPermName((String) object[1]);
        alicePermissions2.setPermDesp((String) object[2]);
        alicePermissions2.setPermParentId((Integer)object[3]);
        alicePermissions2.setPerm((BigInteger) object[4]);

        alicePermissions.add(alicePermissions2);
    }

    return alicePermissions;
}
```

UserPermissionService.java

```
 public List<Object[]> roleuserPermissionforRole(Integer systemId) {
    return dao.roleuserPermissionforRole(systemId);
}
```

UserPermissionDao.java

```
 public  List<Object[]> roleuserPermissionforRole(Integer systemId){

            List userPermission=super.currentSession().
                    createSQLQuery("select   
 p.prm_permission_id,p.prm_permission_name,p.prm_short_description,p.prm_parent_id,case when 
 rp.rop_permission_id is null then 0 else 1 end as perm from prm_user_permission p left outer 
 join rop_role_permissions rp on p.prm_permission_id = rp.rop_permission_id where prm_system_id 
 ='"+systemId+"'").list();
    return  userPermission;

}
```

I want to delete these data by given an ID before inserting new data.I mean if we give an id="1", then it should remove the all rows data in table where the id=1.Need some guidance on how to delete using a SQL query like the above given select query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I got everything right, but anyway here is a possible solution:

Instead of invoking list() on the query instance, you can invoke executeUpdate(). Among other things, this will send the query to the database in order to update data. Your query might look like

```
super.currentSession().createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM table WHERE id = ?")
```

where ? is a placeholder for the actual value. If you need a more complex constraint, it is up to you to change the WHERE clause. Just send the query to the database before inserting new data (using a different query).

Concerning the parameters of a query, you really should consider using the appropriate methods to set a parameters (see [http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13930)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13930). This will effectively prevent SQL injection.

I hope this helps.